# Associating arbitrary number of variables in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a project (using Firebase for the backend) where we want to associate an arbitrary amount of values with a particular key. We would like to delete/add values freely, and I'm having trouble thinking of a solution for this without using string concatenation, which is not ideal for deletion. Any ideas on a way to handle this?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mongodb`?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any trouble setting up your Firebase location as

```
--keys
----$key
------{someValue}: true
```

Where $key corresponds to whatever key you're storing, and then you'd just set children values with a boolean "true". Assuming JavaScript, you'd have something similar to:

```
var myKey = 'someKey';
var someVal = 'someVal';
var someOtherVal = 'foo';


var fb = new Firebase('https://xyz.firebaseio.com/keys/' + myKey);
fb.child(someVal).set(true);
fb.child(someOtherVal).set(true);
```

Now you can read all of these attributes from the fb reference easily enough.

To delete you could do the following:

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://xyz.firebaseio.com/keys/' + myKey);
fb.child(someVal).remove();
```